# Unknown type name 'RLMSyncCredentials'; did you mean 'RLMCredentials'?

Tags: ios, realm

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>
#import "Log.h"      
RLMSyncCredentials *credential = [RLMSyncCredentials credentialsWithUsername:@"sdf"
                                                                            password:@"fsd@123"
                                                                            register:NO];
[RLMSyncUser logInWithCredentials:credential
                            authServerURL:authURL
                             onCompletion:^(RLMSyncUser *user, NSError *error)
```

I keep getting /sfsf/fsdfsdfds/rel.m:33:5: Unknown type name 'RLMSyncCredentials'; did you mean 'RLMCredentials'?

I have in my pods

pod 'Realm/Headers'
pod 'Realm'

Comment: It appears you're using an older version of Realm and ObjC? Did you add pod 'Realm' to your app target and pod 'Realm/Headers' to your test target? Also, Realm is being discontinued in favor of MongoDB Realm. If you're just getting started, head over to the new [MongoDB Realm](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/) site to get started.

Comment: the problem is its all swift, i need in objective - c.  Yes probably realm got updated since  I did new pod install. It was working 2 months ago

Comment: It's not all Swift - here's the [Objective-C SDK Reference Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/objc/10.1.0). Note that `RLMSyncCredentials` was renamed `RLMCredentials` a while back with the function being `+credentialsWithEmail:password:` for authentication.